# CSV Download from website into R, getting access to the direct link

Tags: javascript, php, html, r, csv

I'm trying to write an R script which allows me to automatically download csv files with variable start and end dates. I want to create a shiny app to download data from for example the last month from a few websites. For most of the websites this is pretty straight forward:

-Access the code of the website

-Find out, which linkstructure they're using ([www.example.com/download/csv/startdate_enddate](http://www.example.com/download/csv/startdate_enddate) or something simular)

-Use that link in my code and define "startdate" and "enddate" as variables which can be modified by userinput.

So far so good, but now i have one particular website, where i can't find out which part of the link is responsible for defining the date range plus they're using hashtags as well. The only link i could extract looks something like this:

```
[https://www.tennet.eu/de/strommarkt/transparenz/transparenz-deutschland/netzkennzahlen/tatsaechliche-und-prognostizierte-windenergieeinspeisung/?tx_tennetcw_transparency%5Baction%5D=csvDownload&tx_tennetcw_transparency%5Bcontroller%5D=Transparency&cHash=4319b4da8058a55eafddb1778fc3c605][2]
```

When i try to open the link it produces an error instead of the desired csv download. I've printed the part of the code which i think is important below. I can't really make sense of it. Maybe one of you can?

```js
<div id="c17801" class="transparency">

        <form method="post" id="dateForm" action="https://www.tennet.eu/de/strommarkt/transparenz/transparenz-deutschland/netzkennzahlen/tatsaechliche-und-prognostizierte-windenergieeinspeisung/?tx_tennetcw_transparency%5Bcontroller%5D=Transparency&amp;cHash=0c5a69f0d1ca095dbb24b00305db7493">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[__referrer][@extension]" value="TennetCw">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[__referrer][@vendor]" value="Arvato">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[__referrer][@controller]" value="Transparency">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[__referrer][@action]" value="list">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[__referrer][arguments]" value="YTowOnt96b882eafe83827345698c053f8021fe553f44326">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[__referrer][@request]" value="a:4:{s:10:&quot;@extension&quot;;s:8:&quot;TennetCw&quot;;s:11:&quot;@controller&quot;;s:12:&quot;Transparency&quot;;s:7:&quot;@action&quot;;s:4:&quot;list&quot;;s:7:&quot;@vendor&quot;;s:6:&quot;Arvato&quot;;}8f91dd11199b4d706eaa7939dfa04d22d7122893">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[__trustedProperties]" value="a:5:{s:9:&quot;daterange&quot;;i:1;s:5:&quot;sDate&quot;;i:1;s:5:&quot;eDate&quot;;i:1;s:7:&quot;current&quot;;i:1;s:5:&quot;email&quot;;i:1;}7bd71ac7c27524cfeea0fd8eb75b19db669075ab">
</div>

            <input id="daterange" type="text" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[daterange]">
            <span class="icon-calendar"></span>
            <span class="input-group-addon btn">
                <a title="CSV Download"><span class="icon-download"></span></a>
            </span>
            <span class="input-group-addon btn">
                <span title="PNG Download" id="chartToImg"><span class="icon-image"></span></span>
            </span>
            <input id="sDate" type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[sDate]" value="">
            <input id="eDate" type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[eDate]" value="">
            <input id="current" type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[current]" value="windPowerFeedIn">
            <input class="email" type="email" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[email]" value="">
        </form>

        <form method="post" id="csvForm" action="https://www.tennet.eu/de/strommarkt/transparenz/transparenz-deutschland/netzkennzahlen/tatsaechliche-und-prognostizierte-windenergieeinspeisung/?tx_tennetcw_transparency%5Baction%5D=csvDownload&amp;tx_tennetcw_transparency%5Bcontroller%5D=Transparency&amp;cHash=4319b4da8058a55eafddb1778fc3c605">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[__referrer][@extension]" value="TennetCw">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[__referrer][@vendor]" value="Arvato">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[__referrer][@controller]" value="Transparency">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[__referrer][@action]" value="list">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[__referrer][arguments]" value="YTowOnt96b882eafe83827345698c053f8021fe553f44326">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[__referrer][@request]" value="a:4:{s:10:&quot;@extension&quot;;s:8:&quot;TennetCw&quot;;s:11:&quot;@controller&quot;;s:12:&quot;Transparency&quot;;s:7:&quot;@action&quot;;s:4:&quot;list&quot;;s:7:&quot;@vendor&quot;;s:6:&quot;Arvato&quot;;}8f91dd11199b4d706eaa7939dfa04d22d7122893">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[__trustedProperties]" value="a:5:{s:7:&quot;current&quot;;i:1;s:3:&quot;uid&quot;;i:1;s:5:&quot;sDate&quot;;i:1;s:5:&quot;eDate&quot;;i:1;s:5:&quot;email&quot;;i:1;}172537dd2ccfc75d9cd1f075558d525c95ff58e2">
</div
            <input type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[current]" value="windPowerFeedIn">
            <input type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[uid]" value="17801">
            <input id="sDateCsv" type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[sDate]" value="2019-01-07">
            <input id="eDateCsv" type="hidden" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[eDate]" value="2019-01-07">
            <input type="hidden" name="type" value="7788">
            <input class="email" type="email" name="tx_tennetcw_transparency[email]" value="">
</div>
```

For me it looks like the variables "tx_tennetcw_transparency[sDate]" with the dates as value are key here. But im stuck trying to modify the link so it downloads any csv at all...
Sorry, if the question sounds stupid to anyone, im not a programming expert :/

Please help!

Cheers! 
YS

Comment: "produces an error"...what error exactly?

Comment: P.S. There's no part of the _link_ which is response for the dates, because the form uses POST - so any code you use to emulate it needs to generate a POST request and include the same data in the request body as the form will include when it posts back to the server. Watch the request in your browser's network tools and you'll see that that content is included in the request body, not in the URL. (GET requests don't have a body, and every bit of data is in the URL on the querystring, but in a POST (and other types) you can have both querystring and body variables.)

Comment: it just redirects me to the mainpage showing "Oops, an error occurred! Code: 20190108144240bf3a9277"

Comment: normally i would just use something like this: date<-read.csv(paste0("https://www.example.com/api/grid-data/items/csv/", date_start,"/", date_end),dec=",",sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = F) to import the file. So with that website, there is no option to do that?

Comment: I don't know R specifically I'm afraid. I imagine you can probably research how to write a HTTP POST request in R, though. Then you'd have to feed the response from that request to your read.csv method.